# Autodesk Viewer Performance

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have problem with large model on Forge Viewer. Although i had translate it to SVF2 but it take so long to load and with any action it rerender all time (i known it a part of process). Are there any solutions like Proxy in 3Dsmax or when camera far from model it show low LOD and when scroll in it show higher LOD? What can i do to speed up model? Appreciate any solutions.

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to confirm that you are really using SVF2 in the viewer? For example, do you see the viewer communicating via WebSockets in the Network tab?

So far we've seen major performance improvements across all projects switching over to this new file format, but it's possible that your model is so large/complex that even SVF2 isn't helping. In that case I'm afraid we won't have other solutions, other than perhaps splitting your design into multiple models, and loading only those that you really need. For example, Navisworks designs are often split by area and/or discipline, and the models are then loaded selectively by specific users. Check out this demo (specifically the checkbox matrix in the sidebar): https://forge-industrial-construction.autodesk.io/facility/montreal.

Comment: im pretty sure im using svf2, im check by method ``viewer.model.isSVF2()`` (i update pic above). Thanks for your information, i just want to know if we have better option to do it faster.